# How do I check for duplicate dictionaries by a key and remove the dictionaries by a different key?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

How do I check for duplicate dictionaries by the key 'initials' and remove the duplicate dictionaries with the lowest 'score' key?

Code:

```
scores = [{'initials': 'AS', 'score': 87},
          {'initials': 'AS', 'score': 23},
          {'initials': 'WI', 'score': 43},
          {'initials': 'WI', 'score': 98}]

(code goes here)

print(scores)
```

Intended output:

```
[{'initials': 'AS', 'score': 87},
 {'initials': 'WI', 'score': 98}],
```

Edit: I realize now that I was supposed to show my current attempt at the problem, but the problem got solved. For my next question I will show my attempt. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Can you share your attempted approach?

Comment: Are you allowed to use modules such as numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scores = [{'initials': 'AS', 'score': 87}, {'initials': 'AS', 'score': 23}, 
{'initials': 'WI', 'score': 43}, {'initials': 'WI', 'score': 98}]


dict_of_dict = dict()
for dic in scores:
    if dic['initials'] not in dict_of_dict:
        dict_of_dict[dic['initials']] = dic
    else:
        if dic['score'] > dict_of_dict[dic['initials']]['score']:
            dict_of_dict[dic['initials']] = dic
    
scores = list(dict_of_dict.values())
```

This is more like keeping the one with max score. I guess that is exactly what you meant.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Also your variable naming is cursed, i love it

Comment: @jjmccrystal There's a reason for that: You should never name Python variables after existing Python objects/functions. Therefore, `dic` is a better, albeit weirder, name than `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

This is yet again an example of where you want to group by a key then aggregate the other keys, in this case, you aggregation is to take `max` of the other keys. So *use the dictionary grouping idiom*:

```
>>> grouper = {}
>>> for d in scores:
...     key = d['initials']
...     if key in grouper:
...         grouper[key] = max(grouper[key], d['score'])
...     else:
...         grouper[key] = d['score']
...
>>> grouper
{'AS': 87, 'WI': 98}
```

At this point, this dictionary is likely a more appropriate data structure for what you want. But if you really must have a list of dicts, you can just transform the above:

```
>>> [dict(initials=k, score=v) for k,v in grouper.items()]
[{'initials': 'AS', 'score': 87}, {'initials': 'WI', 'score': 98}]
```